# how to find all elements and matching partial text in cypress and Javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

I have this DOM Structure

```html
<a href=***engineer-jobs-in-london" data-id="49744949" title="Engineer" class="" data-gtm="sponsored_job_click" data-gtm-value="49744949">
                        Engineer
                    </a>


<a href="***engineer-jobs-in-london" data-id="49948533" title="Engineer" class="" data-gtm="sponsored_job_click" data-gtm-value="49948533">
                        Engineer
                    </a>

<a href="***engineer-jobs-in-london" data-id="49948533" title="Engineer" class="gtmJobTitleClickResponsive" data-gtm="job_click" data-gtm-value="49948533">
                        Engineer
                    </a>

<a href="****engineer-jobs-in-london" data-id="49948533" title="Engineer" class="gtmJobTitleClickResponsive" data-gtm="job_click" data-gtm-value="49948533">
                        Engineer
                    </a>

<a href="***engineer-jobs-in-london" data-id="49744949" title="Engineer" class="gtmJobTitleClickResponsive" data-gtm="job_click" data-gtm-value="49744949">
                        Engineer
                    </a>

<a href="***engineer-jobs-in-london" data-id="49744949" title="Engineer" class="gtmJobTitleClickResponsive" data-gtm="job_click" data-gtm-value="49744949">
                        Engineer
                    </a>

<a href="****engineer-jobs-in-london" data-id="49712390" title="BI Engineer" class="gtmJobTitleClickResponsive" data-gtm="job_click" data-gtm-value="49712390">
                        BI Engineer
                    </a>
```

This is not whole DOM structure, only the relevant part. There are more than 100 anchors tags with similar pattern.

My problem is, I need make sure Engineer text should appear more than 5 times in web page.

Also London should be present more than 5 times in the `href` tag.

I tried this:

```js
 cy.contains('Engineer').should('be.greaterThan', 5)
```

but it always retyring 1 and it throwing Assertion error.

Where is my logic going wrong and what is the correct way implement this logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use another method, since `cy.contains()` only returns the **first element** (so count is always 1 with cy.contains()).

Try this instead, it does the same thing in a different way to get the actual count of `<a>` elements with "Engineer" text.

```js
cy.get('a:contains(Engineer)')
  .its('length')
  .should('be.greaterThan', 5)
```